# Tried to install Kali Linux and now I can't access macOS anymore

Tags: macos, partition, guid

It has been 3 days, I was trying to recover it but now I am out of options.

I've tried installing Kali Linux on my Mac as a dual boot with a Linux partition of 20.5 GB inside my 500GB SSD and 1GB of swap Linux but after the first boot everything vanished and a black screen with a question mark came. So I searched websites and found @klanomath's answers about fixing the partition table and I messed it up, please help.

[image: diskutil list]

[image: terminal booted through external usb]

1. Maybe I fixed GPT row maybe as shown in pictures through @klanomath's answers.
2. Fdisk isn't fixing up, nothing is showing up there.
3. No core storage volume found within `diskutil cs list`
4. Not able to repair disk via command, unrecognised file system.

Please help, it's the only last data I have of my life. Sorry for my English.

Comment: Please say that you backed up all your information to a separate device before you started this.

Comment: Please help i have important data, I don't know what to do